# PHPExcel unable to get datetime in excel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have used **PHPExcel** to imports value from excel. The problem is when php read from datetime excel format column.
Value from excel column: `01/04/2021  12:00:00 AM`

But I get the results in php is `1905-07-13`

My code as below.

```
$InvoiceDate=PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($allDataInSheet[$i]["G"]);
$InvoiceDate=date("Y-m-d", $InvoiceDate);
```

Comment: Can you show what does `$InvoiceDate` contain before you apply the `date` command? Basically `var_dump($InvoiceDate)` after the first line.

Comment: I got this value before apply date command. `-2034547200`

Comment: If `$allDataInSheet[$i]["G"]` is correctly set to `01/04/2021  12:00:00 AM` then it means that the `ExcelToPHP` is unable to correctly transform that value in a Unixtimestamp. Try this `$InvoiceDate=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($allDataInSheet[$i]["G"]));`

Comment: The result was `2021-06-02` when i used  `$InvoiceDate=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($allDataInSheet[$i]["G"]));`

Comment: Can you echo `$allDataInSheet[$i]["G"]` ?

Comment: I got this `2021-06-02 15:49:29`

Comment: So it's correct that my previous function returned `2021-06-02`... it's the same date as your initial code but removing the time. Not sure what the issue is...